# Biggest number in the array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code:

```
    void main()
 {
     int x;
     scanf("%d", &x);
     int array[x];
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<x; i++)
     {
         scanf("%d", &array[i]);
     }
     int j;
     for(i=0; i<x-1; i++)
     {
         if(array[i]>=array[i+1])
            j=array[i];
         else j=array[i+1];
     }
     printf("%d", &j);
 }
```

And I want to print the biggest number in the array. But it always returns a giant random number and I'm struggling to find my mistake here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're passing the address of `j` to printf

Comment: Holy, Don't tell me that's the problem.

Comment: That was it. I feel so dumb right now. Thanks for correcting me, mate! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably messed up `scanf` and `printf`. `scanf` requires a pointer e.g 
`scanf("%d", &j);` (in order to change the value of the variable) but in printf you shouldn't pass a pointer so `printf("%d", &j);` should be `printf("%d", j);` (since `printf` only prints the value of the variable and doesn't change it)

Answer (score 1):

Change this code snippet

```
 int j;
 for(i=0; i<x-1; i++)
 {
     if(array[i]>=array[i+1])
        j=array[i];
     else j=array[i+1];
 }
 printf("%d", &j);
              ^^^
```

the following way

```
 int j = array[0];
 for ( i = 1; i < x; i++ )
 {
     if ( j < array[i] ) j = array[i]; 
 }
 printf( "%d", j );
              ^^^
```

The original code snippet does not search the greatest element (consider fpr example an array containing the following elements `{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }`) and the second argument of the call of printf is specified incorrectly.

Take into account that the name `x` is not suitable for the number of elements in an array. It is much better to use for example the name `n`.

Also according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 void main()
 {
     int x;
     scanf("%d", &x);
     int array[x];
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<x; i++)
     {
         scanf("%d", &array[i]);
     }
     int j = a[0];
     for(i=1; i<x; i++)
     {
         if(array[i] > j)
            j=array[i];
     }
     printf("%d", j);
 }
```

You are comparing two consecutive elements of array

```
array[i] >= array[i+1]
```

which is not the correct logic. You should compare each element of array with biggest number found yet (as storing in j)

```
array[i] > j
```

Also you cannot pass address of variable to printf() function. It should be like this

```
printf("%d", j);
```

Comment: You're right, the way you say makes much more sense. I'll use it from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int max(int *a, size_t size)
{
  int max = INT_MIN;
  size_t i = 0;
  while(i < size) 
  {
    if(a[i] > max) max = a[i] ;
    i++;
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: What does the "*" mean? I'm completely new to programming so I didn't really get it, but aside from that, I think I understand your code. It makes much more sense than mine, thanks! haha

Comment: Adding a little description regarding your answer would be great.